# How to get user roles and display on usercard angular5

Tags: angular

I have a document in the firestore. Users with roles in object form:

```
ktwmsjEnRxaVja8RFdSBAwSE7yi2
   uid: 'ktwmsjEnRxaVja8RFdSBAwSE7yi2',
   username: 'some user',
   **roles: 
        admin: false,
        user: true,
        dealer: false**
   updatedAt: 3938y349'
```

When I do an `*ngFor="let user of users | async`,
I can get the user info on template with `user.name`. All good.

But how do I display on the user card their different roles?

if user has a role of `user, admin`, I want to display that on the template. Do I do another *ngFor on the `user.roles`?

I want to display all `true` roles.

Comment: yes you are right.you have to used nested *ngFor

Comment: I tried something like this `*ngFor="let role of user['roles']"`  and `{{role}}` it didn't work. What is the way to do it?

Comment: try *ngFor="let role of user.roles"

Comment: I did that too :) but didn't get nothing to display.

Comment: roles is collection ?

Comment: no it's not. It's an object under the user collection.. If I just do `user.roles` it displays [Object, Object]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162211/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-obasi-obeny-oj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If roles is not a collection then no need to use *`ngFor` you can simply use interpolation syntax in the template as shown below

```
{{user.roles.admin}}
```